# Python Oracle successfully connected, but no query results returned

Tags: python, oracle

I'm setting up a connection to Oracle in Python. I think the connection was good, as there was no error message after I executed the following lines, plus the con.version was printed just as normal,

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect(
    "{}/{}@{}".format(username, password, database_alias))
print (con.version)
cursor = con.cursor()
```

However, when I then tried to query with the following lines,

```
query='select * from some_table'
cursor.execute(query)
```

There was no query results returned and `cursor.rowcount` returned zero, no matter which table I tried, even though the query worked beautifully in Oracle Developer.

Comment: Could you please provide the output of con.version and more information about the tables?

Comment: It's 11.2.0.3.0. I tried couple of tables and they are just regular Oracle data tables that I usually retrieve data from in R without any problem. Thanks.

Comment: I solved my own problem! After converting the query result to a data frame by using this, I can see the data,df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall()). Cheers!!!